# Compare TextBox Controls by Name property

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I have a `KeyPress` event bound on multiple `TextBox`s and I want to check which `TextBox` is getting clicked and do different things depending on the one clicked.

I'm trying to compare which `TextBox` is getting clicked based on the `.Name` attribute of the text box. I'm doing this in a switch statement, but am getting `a Constant value is expected`.

```
private void UpdateValues(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textBox = (TextBox)sender;

    switch (textBox.Name)
    {
        case txtBox1.Name: // Error here
            break;
    }
}
```

Is there a way to get around this? I don't want to hard code the `.Name` as a `string` in case future developers work on this.

Can I do this, or will it become a run time error?

```
private const string _TXTBOX1NAME = txtBox1.Name;


private void UpdateValues(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textBox = (TextBox)sender;

    switch (textBox.Name)
    {
        case _TXTBOX1NAME: // Use the const variable
            break;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Actually, you cannot assign `const` values like that.

How would I compare which `TextBox` has a `KeyPress` without hard coding the `.Name` as a string in the `case` statement?

Comment: Have you tried?

Comment: no you cannot do that, constant values must be derived from compile time constants.  Not sure of a good efficient way of doing what you're asking without looping through all the controls of the form.  this wouldnt be very efficient.  EDIT.  see my answer, i realized if you're willing to use a switch, then if/elseif patter will work as well

Comment: Why do you have the same event handler hooked up to multiple textboxes if you want to do different things depending on the textbox? You might consider breaking out the functionality into a method or two, then hook up different event handlers to the controls that require different functionality, calling the common methods where appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use the `switch` like that. The `case`s need to be compile-time constants.

You could do:

```
private void UpdateValues(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textBox = (TextBox)sender;

    switch (textBox.Name)
    {
        case "NameTextBox": 
            break;
        case "PasswordTextBox":
            break;
    }
}
```

If you know the names, this would be possible. Your example fails, because `textbox1.Name` is not a constant, but a property read from the instance of one `TextBox`.

Another way would be to use the textbox reference, given as the sender:

```
private void UpdateValues(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textBox = (TextBox)sender;

    if(textBox == textBox1) { ... }
    if(textBox == textBox2) { ... }
}
```

But IMHO the best solution would be to use two change-callbacks, one for each method. Then you do not need to compare the `textbox`es or the `textbox`'s names.

So you could change `UpdateValues` into one `UpdateUserName` and `UpdatedPasswort`. Doing this, the method name will clearly show, what the method does(, or at least should do), making your code a lot more readable.

Comment: The cast is unnecessary - you can just do `if (sender == textBox1)`

Comment: @RufusL you are right, I just assumed one would need to access the textbox in the if-bodies, therefore I included the cast.

Comment: Sure, that makes sense! Although they do have access to the textbox by using the one on the right side of the `==` operator. Not a big deal, just a tip to save some typing and a tiny bit of memory.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
private void UpdateValues(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textBox = (TextBox)sender;

    if (textBox.Name == textBox1.Name){
          //error
    } else if(textBox.Name == textBox2.Name){
          // and so on
    }
}
```